# Is it possible to build this header layout using Flexbox CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I've been trying to figure out how to make this layout possible in CSS Flexbox, so far cannot figure out a way to make it work that doesn't involve hiding a duplicate  to show only on desktop. Is this possible to do using Flexbox?

Image example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Flexbox question]

Comment: does a grid solution would be acceptable?

Comment: @KakSarkar yes, would appreciate any possible suggestions. I assumed flexbox would be the only way, happy to try anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in `grid` would be a lot nicer and this is a working example the breakpoint for mobile version happens in 800px,

I suggest you read the [Grid Area Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) system it make these kind of layouts in very modern and nice way

```css
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "blue red""blue red""green green";
  gap: 10px;
}

.blue{
  grid-area: blue;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.red{
  grid-area: red;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.green{
  grid-area: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .parent{
 grid-template-areas:    "blue red"
                         "blue green";
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```